# "Unknown Identifier 'FileOpen'" when trying to detect locked file in Inno Setup code

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

I am attempting to use `FileOpen` in Inno Setup code, however the Inno Setup compiler keeps throwing me the following error.

> Unknown Identifier 'FileOpen'

Here is a sample code:

```pascal
function IsFileLocked(pathFile : string) : Boolean;
var
  hFile : integer;
begin
  Result := true;

  hFile := FileOpen(pathFile);
  if (0 <> hFile) then
    begin
      Result := false;

      { Since ISPP 1.2, Inno Setup automatically frees resources, so FileClose() is obsolete. }
      { http://www.jrsoftware.org/ispphelp/index.php?topic=fileclose }
    end;
end;
```

Unlike the `FileClose` method, `FileOpen` is not obsolete.

[FileOpen](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ispphelp/index.php?topic=funcs)

I did a Google search, but nothing turned up. I know that Inno Setup uses Pascal Script, not Pascal, but the `FileOpen` function is part of the `Inno Setup Preprocessor: Functions`.

Note: I upgraded to the latest version of the compiler (5.6.1a) this morning and the latest version of Inno Script Studio (2.3.0), same problem.

I do see the section `Other Information > ISPPBuiltins.iss`. I tried adding the line:

```
[Code]
#include <ISPPBuiltins.iss>
```

Adding the `#include` statement, generates the error

> ISPPBuiltins.iss Line 1: Column 1:'BEGIN' expected.

Adding in `ISPPBuiltins.iss` to the project as a method to solve the `FileOpen` problem is meaningless, as opening the file in a text editor shows that 'FileOpen` does not exist in there. I do not see any embedded file. It would appear that the compiler does not like "; BEGIN..." in the file, but I digress. So much for that thought.

Thoughts on how to resolve my Unknown Identifier problem with `FileOpen`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`FileOpen`](https://jrsoftware.org/ispphelp/index.php?topic=fileopen) is a [preprocessor](https://jrsoftware.org/ispphelp/) function. You cannot use it in Pascal Script code, which has [its own function library](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptfunctions).

- For quick and dirty solution, use [`LoadStringFromFile`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_loadstringfromfile).
- For a more clean and efficient solution, [import `CreateFile` WinAPI function](https://web.archive.org/web/20160616224242/http://www.vincenzo.net/isxkb/index.php?title=CreateFile_%28%29).